# Check if string is empty with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am running a client side validation javascript which will submit a form via an ajax post after validating the data. Here is the javascript:

```
$(".button").click(function() {

            $(".error").hide();

            var name = $(":input.name").val();
            if ((name == "") || (name.length < 4)){

                $("label#nameErr").show();
                $(":input.name").focus();
                return false;
            }

            var email = $(":input.email").val();
            if (email == "") {

                $("label#emailErr").show();
                $(":input.email").focus();
                return false;
            }


            var phone = $(":input.phone").val();
            if (phone == "") {

                $("label#phoneErr").show();
                $(":input.phone").focus();
                return false;
            }

            var comment = $("#comments").val();
            if ((!comment) || (comment > 100)) {

                $("label#commentErr").show();
                $("#comments").focus();
                alert("hello");
                return false;
            }

            var info = 'name:' + name + '&email:' + email + '&phone:' + phone + '&comment:' + comment;
            var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php"); ?>';
            alert(info);

            jQuery.ajax({

                type:"post",
                dataType:"json",
                url: myAjax.ajaxurl,
                data: {action: 'submit_data', info: info},
                success: function(response) {
                    if (response.type == "success") {

                        alert("success");
                    }
                    else {

                        alert("fail");
                    }
                }
            });

            $(":input").val('');
            return false;


        });
```

The four input fields are three text inputs for name, email and phone and then one textarea for the comments/queries section. The problem is that if I leave the textarea blank  or enter over 100 characters the script does not go into the if ((!comment) || (comment > 100))
statement. I am wondering if there is a different value that gets assigned to a textarea when it is blank that is stopping the code from seeing it as empty ?

Comment: Hello!  Don't forget to accept an answer - you even get 2 rep for it!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to check the `length` property of `comment` (also, you have a few extra parens.  They won't break anything, but aren't needed).

```
if (!comment || comment.length > 100) {
```

What's currently happening is that you're trying to determine if a given string is less than a number, which is quite silly, so JS declares it false.  Checking `comment.length` compares it to a number, which is what you wanted it to do.

`!comment` works because an empty string is falsy, though what you *think* is empty might not be (for instance, a string with a space is non-empty: `' '`).  Use `.trim()` to eliminate that pesky whitespace:

```
if (!comment.trim() && comment.length > 100)
```

(as a side note, none of the above requires jQuery, it's all JavaScript)

Comment: Why doesn't it work if the OP leaves the field blank, though? *"The problem is that if I leave the textarea blank or enter over 100 characters..."*

Comment: i related to this in my answer, not handling Trim condition

Comment: !comment just handles case of undefined or null (null in some cases)

Comment: @OriRefael it also handles cases of empty strings, as I've explained.

Comment: @SomeKittensUx2666: `String#trim` is still missing for browsers in significant use in the wild.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#String.prototype.trim All of the latest browsers support it.  One doesn't need to include legacy support unless it's specifically requested: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/133534/179812

Comment: @SomeKittensUx2666: I prefer not to have my code fail for between 6% (if you ask statcounter) and 21% (if you ask NetApplications) of my visitors. IE8 is not, yet, a legacy browser. We all want it to be, but it isn't.

Comment: Since when trim is available in JS? For IE - since version 9? Well, looks like one still needs JQuery to have trim in IE8.

Answer (score 2):

You have two symptoms:

1. Leaving the field blank doesn't trigger the condition, and
2. Entering more than 100 characters doesn't trigger the condition.

The others have pointed out why #2 doesn't happen: You're doing `comment > 100` where you need `comment.length > 100`.

The first is most likely because the field *isn't* completely blank, but rather has some whitespace in it. We can remove that whitespace with jQuery's `$.trim` (which works cross-browser, whereas `.trim` on strings doesn't work in IE8). So:

```
var comment = $.trim($("#comments").val()); // trim removes leading and trailing whitespace
if ((!comment) || (comment.length > 100)) { // Include .length
```

That's assuming you don't want to count leading and trailing whitespace.

Answer (score -1):

```
if ( comment == '' || comment.length > 100 ) {
```

Comment: But...  it works.  OP didn't use the .length property to check the length of the comment.  (user I am replying to deleted their post)

Comment: @user2864740 So for you, `comment > 100` and `comment.length > 100` are the same? Wow...

Comment: @Shomz Ahh, yes. Missed that bit in the other change. Just rationally explain/expand the answer.

Comment: @Shomz: This is why it's important not just to dump updated code, but to say **what** you changed, and **why**. Also: The OP said it didn't work when they left the field blank; this doesn't address that at all.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I know and I agree, but this was so straightforward I really thought no explanation was needed. And it does address the empty field.

Comment: @Shomz you should know better than that. To us maybe it's trivial, to noobies? It's the most confusing thing ever at the time.

Comment: @Shomz: *"And it does address the empty field."* No, it doesn't. The OP's code had `!comment` in it. `!comment` will be true if `comment == ''` is true.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder http://jsfiddle.net/xrdmL/ Empty string is falsy, so OP's code evaluates to true, so does mine: http://jsfiddle.net/xrdmL/1/

Comment: @Shomz: Oh for cryin' out loud: The OP was using `!comment` and also said *"if I leave the textarea blank...(it doesn't work)"* So that tells us `!comment` wasn't catching the case the OP was talking about. And nor will the above.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Are you complaining about the whitespaces?

Answer (score -2):

one reason that everyone here are making a mistake, if i provide an empty string which contains 100 empty spaces they return true.

the current and right way to check for empty string is

```
if (!comment && comment.trim().length > 100)
```

`trim` actually mean that empty spaces from the begining and end of the string are deleted.

Comment: `String#trim` is still missing on browsers in significant use in the wild.

Comment: Disagree, works on Opera, I.E, Firefox, Chrome and Avant, also on mobile browsers.

Comment: @ Ori: *sigh* IE8 is still in significant use in the wild (depending who you ask, between 6.2% and 21.4% here in April 2014). And it doesn't have `String#trim`.